# Wait until a condition becomes true in bash

Tags: bash, shell

When writing shell scripts, I repeatedly have the need to wait for a given condition to become true, e.g. a remote URL becoming available (checked with curl) or a file that should exist, etc.

Ideally, I'd like to have a function or script `await` such that I can write, e.g.,

```
await [[ some condition ]]
```

and it would check the condition every second until it becomes true or a timeout occurs. Ideally I can set the polling interval and the timeout.

Is there a tool for this out there?

Comment: how about `await() {until "$@" ; do sleep 1 ; done  }` ?  `until` will execute the supplied arguments as a command with arguments until the command returns true (if it returns false, it will try again). Good luck.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an `until` loop:

```
until some condition
do
  sleep 5
done
```

e.g.

```
until nc -z localhost 22
do
  echo "SSHd is not up yet. Waiting..."
  sleep 5
done
```

If you want to add a timeout, you'll have to add that separately with a counter or using the [internal `SECONDS` variable](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html):

```
SECONDS=0
until nc -z localhost 22
do
  
  if (( SECONDS > 60 ))
  then
     echo "Giving up..."
     exit 1
  fi

  echo "SSHd is not up yet. Waiting..."
  sleep 5
done
```

Comment: Really good. And if your command isn't expensive, you might as well have your sleep be sub-second. That is supported in Unixy things for the last few decades, where only integers worked before.  `sleep 0.1`

Answer (score 4):

I'd use the `timeout` utility around a `while` loop that uses `sleep`.

E.g.:

```
timeout 1 bash -c 'while :; do echo check; sleep 0.1; done '
```

Comment: This is a great one-liner solution. I used it to wait for git and docker to be installed: `timeout 300 bash -c 'while :; do hash docker && hash git; sleep 0.1; done'`